# Bootstrap v2.3.2 Modal and MVC Controller not working together

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap-2

I am using this HOWTO for MVC and Bootstrap modal

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/826002/Bootstrap-Modal-Dialog-Loading-Content-from-MVC-Pa

```
$('body').on('click', '.modal-link', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).attr('data-target', '#modal-container');
                $(this).attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
            });
```

This part of code does not work with Bootstrap 2.3.2

```
$(this).attr('data-target', '#modal-container');
```

MVC Controller is not executed. Just Empty Modal is shown. In HOWTO they are using Bootstrap 3.2 but I can not upgrade to version 3. Is there any workaround or solution for this kind of problem?